# 'twistd' is not a recognized internal or external command

Tags: python, twisted

I'm trying to develop a Twisted Web server but can't seem to run the `twistd` command. I've tried setting the python path and even included the path to the `twistd.py` script in my Path but nothing seems to work.

I'm using Twisted 12.0.0 and Python 2.7 on Windows. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `%PATHEXT%` environment variable to include `.py`, as well as `%PATH%` including the path to `twistd`.  Your most-recently-installed version of Python should then automatically launch it, assuming the filetype association was set correctly by the installer.

Comment: hmm it still doesn't work... are the % signs significant? On windows 7 the variables are just called "path" and "pathext"

Comment: On Windows, environment variables are *expanded* by surrounding the variable with `%` characters in the shell.  On UNIX, environment variables are expanded by prefixing the variables with the `$` character.  So it is conventional to refer to a Windows environment variable as, for example, `%PATH%`, whereas it is conventional to refer to UNIX variables as, for example, `$PATH`.  (Also, the variables are `PATH` and `PATHEXT`, not `path` and `pathext`.  Case matters.)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `twistd.bat` and save it under your `Scripts` directory; if you're using virtualenv, the exact path is:
`<virtualenv_root_dir>\Scripts\twistd.bat`

Edit `twistd.bat` and put the ff:

```
@echo off
python %~dp0twistd.py %*
```

Assumptions:

- There should be a `<virtualenv_root_dir>\Scripts\twistd.py` after installing `Twisted` in your virtualenv.
- `<virtualenv_root_dir>\Scripts` is in your `%PATH%`

Then after activating your virtualenv, you should be able to run `twistd` directly, e.g.

`twistd web --path . --port 8080`

I myself uses this approach in a Windows XP machine.